# JBoss 7 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I installed Jboss7 into my Eclipse Oxygen.

When I write into my browser: http://localhost:8080/jbossws I cannot reach the page:

[image]

When I write http://localhost:8080 I have the following result

[image]

What is missing into my installation?

Comment: check your context-root check the Administration Console and see what applications are installed, and what the context root there is.

Comment: Hi @MrSimpleMind, looks like I have no applications installed.

Comment: what do you expect to see in jbossws ? If no applications installed/deployed then thats why you get the error. When you deploy an app then you assign it a context-root like /myfirst-app or /jbossws etc

Answer (score 0):

The url does not exist in JBoss AS 7.x or above. You should add a JBoss Admin user (with the add_user.sh/bat) With the url http://localhost:9990 (If you have not changed the port.) you can reach the admin console. Under Deployment are the web services.